# Periodic points in C^2

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, polynomials

I came up with a problem which is similar to the following quesitons:

Consider a map: $f(x,y)=(y^2-2,xy-2)$. It is seems that the number of periodic points of given period is bounded.

I want to apply the argument of a bounded variety in $C^n$ is just a set of finite points.
However, I can not prove the the set of period points is bounded. By numeric computation, It seems that it is true.

I do not know whether there are some big results related to this question.

Edit: In the privious version of the question $f(x,y)=(xy-2,y^2-2)$, I take a mistkake in editing. In fact, $f(x,y)=(y^2-2,xy-2)$. I thank Professor Noam D. Elkies's quick response for the early version of the question which is corresponded to $f(x,y)=(xy-2,y^2-2)$.

Comment: Write $f^n(x,y)=(P_n(x,y),Q_n(x,y))$. Then the points of period dividing $n$ are the solutions to the pair of equations $P_n(x,y)=x$ and $Q_n(x,y)=y$. Each of these equations defines a curve, and each of these curves has a finite number of irreducible components. There will be an infinite number of solutions in $\mathbb{C}^2$ if and only if these two curves have a common component. If your map extended to a regular map on $\mathbb{P}^2$, then it's easy, but your map is not defined at $[1,0,0]$. So one probably needs to do some non-trivial geometry.

Comment: If $|x| > 2$ and $|y|>2$ then $|xy-2|$ and $|y^2-2|$ will both be larger, so the points will escape to $\infty$ and not be periodic. So the issue is points with $x$ very large and $y$ very small or $y$ very large and $x$ very small. You can figure out additional things about the bad points - for instance when $y$ is large, $|x|\leq 2/y$ but I don't see how to get nonexistence.

Answer (score 2):

There are infinitely many $3$-periodic points, with $y = 2 \cos 2\pi n/7\ $
($n=1,2,3$).

Likewise $y = 2 \cos 2\pi n/23 \ $ is $11$-periodic for $1 \leq n \leq 11$, 
"etc."

Comment: In general this works at least when $7$ or $23$ is generalized
to a prime $p \equiv -1 \bmod 8$ for which $-2$ is a primitive residue (any $x$ yields $(x,y)$ of period $(p-1)/2$).

Comment: Thank you. I am sorry for a mistake in editing of this question. f should be $f(x,y)=(y^2-2,xy-2)$

Comment: In the privious version of the question $f(x,y)=(xy-2,y^2-2)$, I take a mistkake in editing. In fact, $f(x,y)=(y^2-2,xy-2)$. I thank Professor Noam D. Elkies's quick response for the early version of the question which is corresponded to $f(x,y)=(xy-2,y^2-2)$.